# Understanding matrix of cofactors

Tags: determinant

Suppose we're working within the vector space of $2 \times 2$ matrices over $\mathbb{R}$. For any matrix, 
$$A = \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix},$$
it should be the case that, irrespective of whether or not $A$ is invertible, there exists a matrix $B$ such that
$$AB = BA = \det A \cdot I,$$
and $B$ is the matrix of cofactors.

In this lecture I am watching, the professor argues that the matrix of cofactors of the above matrix $A$ is given by 
$$\begin{pmatrix} d & -b \\ -c & a\end{pmatrix}.$$
Though this should be correct because the result gives $ad - bc$ along the main diagonal and zeroes everywhere else, which is a scalar multiple, $\det A$, of $I$, I am for some reason not able to rederive the result. If I take $A$ and compute the matrix of minors, I get: 
\begin{align*}
\text{minor}(1,1) & = \det(d) = d \\
\text{minor}(1,2) & = \det(c) = c \\
\text{minor}(2,1) & = \det(b) = b \\
\text{minor}(2,2) & = \det(a).= a.
\end{align*}
The matrix of cofactors is, hence, 
$$\begin{pmatrix} d & -c \\ -b & a \end{pmatrix}.$$
This doesn't match, and I cannot figure out what I have done wrong, even though I am sure it is probably rather obvious.

Could someone take a look at this? In addition, I would be very interested in truly understanding the underlying purpose of these computations. This isn't the way I originally learned determinants, but I am sure there is more meaning to it than brute-force computation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the matrix in the relationship $AB=BA=\det A\cdot I$ is not the cofactor matrix but the [adjugate matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix), the transpose of the cofactor matrix.

This works because the product yields the [Laplace expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_expansion) (also called the cofactor expansion) of the determinant in the diagonal elements and the Laplace expansion of the determinant of a matrix with identical rows or columns (and thus $0$) in the off-diagonal elements.

Comment: Thank you, this was extremely helpful.